# Cirdan actually talking

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

I've now read The Hobbit, LoTR, Silmarillion, Children of Hurin and Unfinished Tales. The only time I've seen Cirdan actually quoted was in the Unfinished Tales: Essay on the Istari. Talking about the conversation between Cirdan and Gandalf:

> 'For' he [Cirdan] said, 'great labour and perils lie before
>   you[Gandalf], and lest your task prove too great and wearisome, take
>   this Ring for your aid and comfort. It was entrusted to me only to
>   keep secret, and here upon the West-shores it is idle; but I deem
>   that in days ere long to come it should be in nobler hands than mine,
>   that may wield it for the kindling of all hearts to courage'.

Is this the only recording of Cirdan actually speaking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's another record of him speaking in the Círdan material in HoME 12:

> And the voice warned him not to attempt this peril; for his strength and skill would not be able to build any ship able to dare the winds and waves of the Great Sea for many long years yet. "Abide now that time, for when it comes then will your work be of utmost worth, and it will be remembered in song for many ages after." **"I obey," Círdan answered**, and then it seemed to him that he saw (in a vision maybe) a shape like a white boat, shining above him, that sailed west through the air, and as it dwindled in the distance it looked like a star of so great a brilliance that it cast a shadow of Círdan upon the strand where he stood.

Unfortunately it's quite a short essay, but it contains much information about this fascinating character that's found nowhere else, and is definitely well-worth reading.